# Understanding of Convolutional Neural Network (CNN)

Tags: machine-learning, cnn

I am a beginner in ML and I would like to learn CNN with Math behind. If you suggest any good blog or documentation which help me get depth knowledge about CNN.

Comment: Welcome to our community :) The best start point can be pr. Ng's deep learning course on Coursera. For math part, you can read the 10th chapter I guess or maybe 9th chapter of deep learning book written by pr. Bengio and dr. Goodflow. You can also track the `CNN` tag in our community.

Comment: [Link to Deep Learning Book by Goodfellow et al](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Following blog posts would be helpful for Visualization and *intuitive understanding*:

- [Understanding Convolutions](http://colah.github.io/posts/tags/convolutional_neural_networks.html) - To understand the basic operation involved, Convolution in 1-D setting
- [Conv Nets: A Modular Perspective](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-Conv-Nets-Modular/) - To understand its usage in construction of CNN ( 2-D setting )